# drag tail(arrow) of Speech bubble on div border

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am creating a speech bubble and I want to drag the tip of the speech bubble all around the corner of the bubble with the mouse. It should also rotate automatically depending on which side it is on.
the tail that is moving it must be in all direction i mean it should be draggable to all the side of the divs now it is for only one side and it must be on mouse drag..so that i can drag my tail by using mouse where ever i want bt that should be only across the border only..plz some give solution.

It is My Speech Bubble CSS:-

```
 .SpeechBubble {
                position: absolute;
                background: red;
                border: 1px solid #F2F2F2;
                opacity: 0.9;
                top: 58px;
                left: 18px;
                width: 153px;
                height: 40px;
                min-width: 47px;
                min-height: 38px;
                position: absolute;
            }



.SpeechBubble:after, .SpeechBubble:before {
                top: 100%;
                border: solid transparent;
                content: " ";
                height: 0;
                width: 0;
                position: absolute;
                pointer-events: none;
            }



.SpeechBubble:after {
                border-top-color: red;
                border-width: 12px;
                left: 50%;
                margin-left: -14px;
            }
<div class="SpeechBubble"></div>
```

Comment: like Example :http://jsfiddle.net/K9t6S/2/. with Draggable and Resizable. plese Give Solution.!!!

Comment: What have you actually tried?...

Comment: when i hold the tail(arrow) of speeech bubble to drag on div border using my mouse.

Comment: Plese See that Example:jsfiddle.net/K9t6S/2/.To Drag The Tail on Div Border.